# Add more than one queue to rabbitmq queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, bigdata

I am using one queue which is hello but I want to add another queue hello1. My code is here below;

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello',hello1)
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='hello')
connection.close()
```